# Wp_Schedule_Event every few minutes doesn't work

Tags: php, functions, hooks, cron

I wrote the folowing timer in my function.php file. It should be called every certain time (3 minutes) but it doesn't work at all.

```
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {

 $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
      'interval' => 180, 
      'display'  => __( 'Every 3 minutes' ),
  );
  return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
}

add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'do_anything' );
```

and here is my function:

```
function do_anything($user_id) {
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'alg_wc_ev_is_activated', '0' );
  wp_redirect(  wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) );
  exit();
}
```

I don't know, why it doesn't work. Am I missing something in code?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how WP Scheduling works. It runs in the background, and has no connection to whoever is logged in at the time. It's meant to do stuff "behind the scenes". It doesn't know what your `$user_id` is, and it can't redirect, because it isn't connected to a user session.

Comment: Thans for your feedback. is there any way that I can update a value in DB after a certain time?